# kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property has not been initialized

Tags: spring, kotlin

This is my main function

```
object Service {
  fun getConfigMappings(client: RedissonClient, request: GetRequest): IndataType {
        ****
        return obj
  }
}
```

I calling it in my main class, and everything works good, I can get the response.

```
@Autowired
lateinit var client: RedissonClient

val indataObj = Service.getConfigMappings(client, request)
```

When I want to write a test for it, I got error "kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property client has not been initialized", can anyone help me with that?
"

```
class ServiceTest {
    @Autowired
    lateinit var client: RedissonClient

    @Test
    fun `test1`() {

        val request = GetRequest {
            ***
        }

        val indataObj = Service.getConfigMappings(client, request)

      }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to use @Autowired, there must have a @Bean somewhere

Answer (score 0):

`kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property has not been initialized` is occured because there is no configuration for `AutoWired`.

If you want to use `AutoWired` in the unit test, it needs annotation for configuration.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations="classpath:config/springbeans.xml")
public class BeanSpringTest {
```